# "Processing inclusion from feature" error while exporting a plugin project to a Product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I get the following error when I try to build a product for my plugin-based project.

`Processing inclusion from feature org.eclipse.pde.container.feature: Bundle org.apache.jdo_3.0.0 failed to resolve.: Missing required plug-in org.datanucleus_2.2.2.`

In the product file, when I do a validation, I see several plugins showing a

`Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle:` problem, such as,

`Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle:org.datanucleus; bundle-version="2.2.2"`

However, I all these plugins do exist in the target platform, only the versions are different! Do I need to separately download and include all the missing plugin versions? Seems like a tedious task!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bundle version listed like `bundle-version="2.2.2"` means version 2.2.2 **or higher** so you just need a single version of the plugin with at least the highest version required.

The version can also be written as `bundle-version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"` which means at least 1.0.0 but less than 2.0.0. If you have any of these you might have to have multiple versions of the plugin.

Comment: Hi Gregg, I included one such missing plugin called javax.wsdl-1.5.1 in order to correct the bundle-version="[1.5.0,1.6.0)" error. The plugin is now included in the target platform but still shows missing in validation. Same is the case for  org.junit4 (4.8.1). I downloaded them from random websites on the internet.